# How to put a horizontal frame containing a couple of widgets into a default vertical frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a layout that is vertical, with some horizontal rows containing a few widgets. When I add the first row it goes fine, but the second row goes at the end of the first row and not back in the vertical frame

I've tried everything I can find with no luck.

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()

frame2 = tkinter.Frame()
frame3 = tkinter.Frame()

frame2.pack()
frame3.pack()

lv1 = tkinter.Label(win, text = "Vertical lab 1")
lv1.pack()
lv2 = tkinter.Label(win, text = "Vertical lab 2")
lv2.pack()

v = tkinter.IntVar()

rb1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(frame2, padx = 10, variable=v,value=1)
rb1.pack()
lh1 = tkinter.Label(frame2, text = "Horizontal lab1")
lh1.pack()
frame2 = tkinter.Frame(win).pack()

rb2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(frame3, padx = 10, variable=v, value=2)
rb2.pack()
lh2 = tkinter.Label(frame3, text = "Horizontal lab2")
lh2.pack()
frame3 = tkinter.Frame(win).pack()

lv3 = tkinter.Label(win, text = "Vertical lab 3")
lv3.pack(anchor="w")

win.mainloop()
```

What I want is something that looks like: One widget on line 1, one widget on line 2, 2 widgets on line 3, 2 widgets on line 4, 1 widget on line 5

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a solution using `.pack()` so I decided to use `.grid()` for labels, radiobuttons inside the frames.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(window)
Label(frame1, text = "Vertical lab 1").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(frame1, text = "Vertical lab 2").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
frame1.pack()

v = IntVar()
frame2 = Frame(window)
rb1 = Radiobutton(frame2, padx = 10, variable=v,value=1)
rb1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(frame2, text = "Horizontal lab1").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
rb2 = Radiobutton(frame2, padx = 10, variable=v,value=1)
rb2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
Label(frame2, text = "Horizontal lab1").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
frame2.pack()

frame3 = Frame(window)
Label(frame3, text = "Vertical lab 3").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
frame3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The output looks like this
[image] 
I presume this is what you were looking for.
 
Also I would like to mention when you use a geometry manager in the same line as you declare it, for example `frame1 = tkinter.Frame().pack()`, here `frame1` is `None` and so is everything else in your code of type `None`, therefore you need to place it afterwards.
As mentioned here https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm don't use  `.pack()` and `.grid()` in the same master window.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.

A widget and a frame containing widget, have a different weight/priority when being placed into a parent window-frame.

Just put ALL widgets into frames, then when they are added to the parent window-frame they will all have the same weight/priority and will appear in the order they were added.

I tested this method and it works perfectly.

(But surely it should not be necessity to do this. Am I still missing something? The corresponding Java layout manager does NOT have this issue! Widgets and frames containing widgets are treated the same.)

Answer (score 1):

For positioning use tkinter grid option:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')

# set widget object
label = Label(window, text="Vertical lab 1")
# set position of widget into grid
label.grid(column=0, row=0)

label = Label(window, text="Vertical lab 2")
label.grid(column=0, row=1)
label = Radiobutton(window, text="Horizontal lab 1", value=0)
label.grid(column=0, row=2)
label = Radiobutton(window, text="Horizontal lab 2", value=1)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)
label = Radiobutton(window, text="Horizontal lab 3", value=0)
label.grid(column=0, row=3)
label = Radiobutton(window, text="Horizontal lab 4", value=1)
label.grid(column=1, row=3)
label = Label(window, text="Vertical lab 3")
label.grid(column=0, row=4)

window.mainloop()
```